# good way to make navbar responsive

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

i have a navbar with 3 buttons on the left hand side and a search bar on the right hand side. i believe i wrote bad(not the proper way) code to make them responsive but still they are not responsive for medium and smaller screens. i am just trying to figure out the good way to make them responsive. i am trying to make a page as shown in the below image.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7l88wv)

```css
  .searchbar{
    width: 400px;
  }
    .btn-primary{
    background-color: #002B42;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  .btn-light{
     margin-left: 30px; 
    padding:10px;

    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    outline: none;
  }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;SAVED LISTS</i></button>      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button class="btn btn-light"> <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp; SAVED FILTER</i>  </button> 
      </li>     
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button class="btn btn-light"> <i class="fa fa-history" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp; SEARCH HISTORY</i>  </button> 
      </li>
    </ul>

  <div class="ml-auto">
    <input class="form-control searchbar" name="search" [(ngModel)]="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
</nav
```

[image: UI design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to set the width `400px` for the `.searchbar` class.
By setting a media query, unfix the navbar for smaller widths. This is more suitable for the user experience.

In my opinion, the most standard is the one Bootstrap itself suggests.
It's best to insert your `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">` into the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-navbar">` and place a button as navbar toggler.
And use the `my-2 my-md-0` class instead of the `ml-auto` class for search wrapper
 as below

```css
body{
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.search-wrapper{
    flex-grow: 1;
   
}
    .btn-primary{
    background-color: #002B42;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  .btn-light{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    outline: none;
  }

  .items{
      margin-top: ;
  }

  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      body{
          padding-top: 0!important;
      }
    .navbar{
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
        align-items: center;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    .nav-item{
        margin:10px 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar" aria-controls="my-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;SAVED LISTS</i></button>      </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <button class="btn btn-light"> <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp; SAVED FILTER</i>  </button> 
                </li>     
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <button class="btn btn-light"> <i class="fa fa-history" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp; SEARCH HISTORY</i>  </button> 
                </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        
        
          <div class="my-2 my-md-0 search-wrapper">
            <input class="form-control searchbar" name="search" [(ngModel)]="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="items">
            <ol>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
                <li>dhsiudshdsds</li>
            </ol>
        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure jquery, popper.js and bootstrap.js are placed in order

Comment: yes its working now but i need to increase search bar width and spacing between each button.

Comment: So you can set flex-grow:1 for search wrapper and margin:10px 0; for each nav-item. I edited the answer